# Return object that implements interface as said interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I'm trying to return an object that implements a certain interface as that interface, but getting Error `CS0030:    Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'T'` at compile time.

My code:

```
public static T GetAncestorOfType<T>(System.Web.UI.Control control)
{
    var parent = control;
    while (!(parent is T))
    {
        parent = parent.Parent;
        continue;
    }
    return (T)parent;
}
```

The error regards the last line, where `parent` is cast to `T`.

Perhaps I need some sort of type constraint on the method?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a constraint and avoid the casting.

```
public static T GetAncestorOfType<T>(T control) where T : System.Web.UI.Control
```

Doing so, the code of you method would become:

```
var parent = control;
while (!(parent is T))
{
    parent = parent.Parent;
    continue;
}
return parent;
```

Comment: I want to be able to call this method with as type parameter an interface. For example, `GetAncestorOfType<IControlWithCertainMethod>(page)`.

Comment: If you want this, then `T` should implement `IControlWithCertainMethod` and not `System.Web.UI.Control`. However then you would have another problem. Probably `Parent` is not a member of `IControlWithCertainMethod`. If so, then your code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `as` operator instead of the cast operator (and add a type constraint), it works.

```
public static T GetAncestorOfType<T>(System.Web.UI.Control control) where T : class
{
    var parent = control;
    while (!(parent is T))
    {
        parent = parent.Parent;
        continue;
    }
    return parent as T;
}
```

The type constraint was suggested by Visual Studio after changing the cast to use `as`.

I don't know why this works!